# How to make an array with 3 objects in one?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

How can I make an array with "3 objects in one" what I want is something like this:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage , NSString , BOOL], [UIImage , NSString , BOOL], nil];
```

Is there some way to do this so that each object at index can have an image, string, and a boolean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
NSArray *array1 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:yourImage , YourString , yourStringBoolValue , nil];

NSArray *array2 = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:array1 , nil];
```

Now `array2` object `0` position contains all your objects as a collection.

To retrieve your values back,use the below code

```
NSArray *retriveArray1 = [array2 objectAtIndex:0];

UIImage *yourImage =    [retriveArray1 objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *yourString =  [retriveArray1 objectAtIndex:1]
BOOL yourBoolValue =    [[retriveArray1 objectAtIndex:2] boolValue];
```